# Split a string into 2 in Python

Tags: python, string, split

Is there a way to split a string into 2 equal halves without using a loop in Python?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Python 2:

```
firstpart, secondpart = string[:len(string)/2], string[len(string)/2:]
```

Python 3:

```
firstpart, secondpart = string[:len(string)//2], string[len(string)//2:]
```

Comment: Or even `firstpart, secondpart = string[::2], string[1::2]` since the question didn't specify that the parts had to be contiguous.

Comment: In python3 :  `firstpart, secondpart = string[:len(string)//2], string[len(string)//2:]`

Comment: little confusing this answer as string stands usually for a keyword - but here the variable is ment ...

Comment: @Dominik `string` isn't a keyword, though it is a [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html), if that's what you're thinking of.

Comment: splice indeces must be int, firstpart, secondpart = string[:int(len(string)/2)], string[int(len(string))/2:]

Answer (score 10):

Whoever is suggesting `string[:len(string)/2], string[len(string)/2]` is not keeping odd length strings in mind!

This works perfectly. Verified on edx.

```
first_half  = s[:len(s)//2]
second_half = s[len(s)//2:]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
a,b = given_str[:len(given_str)/2], given_str[len(given_str)/2:]
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possible approach is to use divmod. rem is used to append the middle character to the front (if odd).

```
def split(s):
    half, rem = divmod(len(s), 2)
    return s[:half + rem], s[half + rem:]

frontA, backA = split('abcde')
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for this. No one has addressed the odd length of the string.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3: 
If you want something like 
madam =>  ma <del>d</del> am 
maam => ma am

```
first_half  = s[0:len(s)//2]
second_half = s[len(s)//2 if len(s)%2 == 0 else ((len(s)//2)+1):]
```

Answer (score 0):

minor correction 
the above solution for below string will throw an error

```
string = '1116833058840293381'
firstpart, secondpart = string[:len(string)/2], string[len(string)/2:]
```

you can do an `int(len(string)/2)` to get the correct answer.

`firstpart, secondpart = string[:int(len(string)/2)], string[int(len(string)/2):]`

Comment: you should use `//` instead of `/` for division.