# how to split number (not character) into two parts in python

Tags: python, split, integer, number-formatting

How do I split a number into two without any arithmetic in python? For example, the table below:

```
20670005000000
30003387889032
44555008000004
```

I want the string to look like the columns below after splitting (and remain numbers that can be used in numerical analysis):

```
2067000  5000000
3000338  7889032
4455500  8000004
```

What's the neatest way to do this in Python? Is there a python module that deals with this directly?

Comment: They look like substrings to me... [maybe this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/is-there-a-way-to-substring-a-string-in-python). To string > substring > parse int

Comment: or even [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789601/split-a-string-into-2-in-python)

Comment: `str(a)[:len(str(a))/2], str(a)[len(str(a))/2:]`, and `a=20670005000000`

Comment: If the number is converted into a string and its length determined with `len` is that considered `arithmetic`?

Comment: have another idea

Answer (score 4):

This is a possible way:

```
N = 10000000
i = 20670005000000

# The first part of the number i
i // N
# the second part
i % N
```

Comment: OP says: `"without any arithmetic"`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is the best way, but you can convert to string, than split it, and convert it to integer again:

```
number = (int(str(number)[:len(number)/2]), int(str(number)[len(number)/2:]))
```

This will give you a touple which you can use later.
You can further optimize this by using list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

you could map the int to str, then split it. remember convert it back to int

```
  data = [20670005000000,
        30003387889032,
        44555008000004,]

  str_data = map(str, data)
  res = map(lambda x: [x[:len(x)//2],x[len(x)//2:]], str_data )
  res = map(int, reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, res) )
  print res
```

output:

```
[2067000, 5000000, 3000338, 7889032, 4455500, 8000004]
```

Comment: Is integer divide by two (`len(x)//2`) *arithmetic*?

Comment: @wwii it is trying to find middle point. it can hard-coded, if op wants a fixed length

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `str.len()` does not involve arithmetic and comparing two integers (`2 > 3`) is NOT arithmetic:

```
import collections
n = 20670005000000

left = collections.deque(str(n))
right = collections.deque()
while len(left) > len(right):
    right.appendleft(left.pop())

left = int(''.join(left))
right = int(''.join(right))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number should be divided exactly at `center` each time, we can use `string` and `slicing` of it to get the two numbers.

Doing with single number here :

```
>>> s = str(20670005000000)
>>> l = int(len(s)/2)
>>> a,b = s[:l],s[l:]
>>> int(a)
=>  2067000   
>>> int(b)
=>  5000000
```

Here, for the List of numbers :

```
for ele in map(str,arr): 
   l = int( len(ele)/2 ) 
   a,b = ele[:l], ele[l:]

   print(int(a), int(b))
```

# driver values

```
IN : arr = [20670005000000, 30003387889032, 44555008000004]

OUT : 2067000 5000000
      3000338 7889032
      4455500 8000004
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the existing pattern of operation in this problem is to divide each string value in half.

```
import re
s = [20670005000000, 30003387889032, 44555008000004]
final_string = [map(int, re.findall('.{'+str(len(str(i))//2)+'}', str(i))) for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[[2067000, 5000000], [3000338, 7889032], [4455500, 8000004]]
```